# xgboost model get training parameters

Tags: r, xgboost

Is it possible to get the training parameters from an xgb.Booster object, built with vanilla xgboost (i.e. no caret wrapping). It only has two fields, namely, handle and raw.

The man pages (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xgboost/xgboost.pdf) did not really give me an answer, and websearching did not yield anything useful. I have a feeling it is not possible to get the training parameters, other than retrieving the nround and max_depth by looking at the model text dump, but I was wondering whether I have missed something.

MWE:

```
library(xgboost)
data(agaricus.train, package='xgboost')
train <- agaricus.train
bstDense <- xgboost(data = as.matrix(train$data), label = train$label, max.depth = 2, eta = 1, nthread = 1, nround = 2, objective = "binary:logistic")
print(xgb.model.dt.tree(feature_names = colnames(train$data), model = bstDense, text = xgb.dump(model = bstDense, with.stats = T)))
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example and describe your expected output

Comment: added mwe, but tbh not sure whether this helps in this case... it is more of a question whether i missed something in the man pages and websearch...

Comment: I've looked at this issue in some depth (including looking at the package source code) and as far as I can tell there is no way of retrieving the original training data from an xgboost R model.  One problem is that xgboost models use xgb.DMatrix objects internally, and you can't retrieve the data from an xgb.DMatrix object using R functions (i.e. xgb.DMatrix objects are write-only!).  IMO the xgboost package should provide a function as.matrix.xgb.DMatrix (or similar) to extract the data from an xgb.DMatrix object.

Comment: many thanks for taking the time to look into it.